# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+100}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series itself:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+100}$$

Actually it should use Leibnitz test, so:

$$\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left|\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+100}\right| = 0$$

So, it converges. but I have to figure out which way:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+100}$$

but which test should I use to check its convergence?

Comment: What do you mean "which way"?

Comment: absolutely or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+100} \ge \frac{\sqrt{n}}{101n}=\frac{1}{101\sqrt{n}} 
$$
and $\sum \frac{1}{101\sqrt{n}}$ diverges, $\sum\frac{(-1)^n \sqrt{n}}{n+100}$ does not converge absolutely.

Comment: why did you compare it with $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{101n}$ exactly?

Comment: @M.Mass To use the comparison test: I assumed that we already know that $\sum n^{-1/2}$ diverges.